# Why use map.call when using map alone does the same thing?

Tags: javascript

This was the question:

> Write a function which takes a ROT13 encoded string as input and
>   returns a decoded string.

I've solved it. Am looking at the given solutions - one of which uses .map.call like so:

```
function rot13(str) {
  return str.split('')
    .map.call(str, function(char) {
      x = char.charCodeAt(0);
      if (x < 65 || x > 90) {
        return String.fromCharCode(x); 
      }
      else if (x < 78) {
        return String.fromCharCode(x + 13);
      }
      return String.fromCharCode(x - 13);
    }).join('');  
}
```

What I don't get is why use `.map.call(str, function(char)` when using `.map(function(char)` would do the exact same thing? I mean I tried it, just removed the .call bit [on repl](https://repl.it/CLjU/4327), and it gives the same result. Or maybe I'm not clear on how .call works. I *have* read the MDN article on it, just still not sure how it works. Or why use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[\].map.call() VS Array.prototype.map.call()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612650/map-call-vs-array-prototype-map-call)

Comment: Your suspicion is correct, the `.call()` is completely superfluous here, and serves no purpose other than to obfuscate and make the function less efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the unspoken question seems to be

> What is the recommended way of implementing this? The given solution looks like gibberish.

a more efficient and readable way to write this would be:

```js
function rotchar(char) {
  const code = char.charCodeAt(0)
  const isUpper = /[A-Z]/.test(char)
  const min = (isUpper ? 'A' : 'a').charCodeAt(0)

  return String.fromCharCode((((code - min) + 13) % 26) + min)
}

function rot13(str) {
  return str.replace(/[A-Z]/gi, rotchar)
}

console.log(rot13('Uryyb Jbeyq'))
console.log(rot13('Hello World'))
```

If you want to implement a generic `rot()`, you could create a factory function. Note that `rot13()` is a special case where encoding and decoding are the same operation. For the rest of them, encoding *adds* the numeric offset to the ASCII index while decoding *subtracts* the numeric offset:

```js
function rot(offset, decode) {
  if (offset < 1 || offset > 25) {
    throw new RangeError('offset must be between 1 and 25')
  }

  // note that when decoding, rotation
  // performs (code + 26 - offset) % 26
  const rotate = decode ? 26 - offset : offset
  
  function rotchar(char) {
    const code = char.charCodeAt(0)
    const isUpper = /[A-Z]/.test(char)
    const min = (isUpper ? 'A' : 'a').charCodeAt(0)

    return String.fromCharCode((((code - min) + rotate) % 26) + min)
  }

  return function rotstr(str) {
    return str.replace(/[A-Z]/gi, rotchar)
  }
}

const rot13 = rot(13)

console.log('rot13:')
console.log(rot13('  Uryyb Jbeyq'))
console.log(rot13('  Hello World'))

const rot12encode = rot(12, false)
const rot12decode = rot(12, true)

console.log('rot12:')
console.log(rot12encode('  Hello World'))
console.log(rot12decode('  Tqxxa Iadxp'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `call` if you want to specify to wich object `this` should point. Using array functions that way is mostly done when the object in question is not an array (and thus doesn't have `obj.map`) but can be treated as an array (like a string or an HTMLCollection). Therefore one could call `[].map.call(obj, callback)` with `obj` being the object on which map should be called.

As you noticed correctly the way it is used here is unnecessarily complicated. Calling `[].map.call(str, ...` or `str.split('').map(...` would be enough.

By the way: `return String.fromCharCode(x);` could be replaced by `return char;`